# Update rows only the first time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

With the trigger that I show below will update the `price` of products to rebates. But I want that in the later insertions, records that the discount has been applied must not be updated.

What can I add?

```
create Trigger tri on t1
after insert As
    UPDATE t1
    SET price = CASE 
                   WHEN column1 = 'Rebate' THEN price * 0.5
                                           ELSE price 
                END
```

Comment: If it's for `AFTER INSERT` instead of `AFTER UPDATE `, isn't the record new anyway?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've changed `after insert` by `after update`, and trigger continues updating all the rows.

Comment: @user_012314112 you can stop the trigger after the first insertion. `disable trigger tri on t1`

Comment: Maybe add a bit column with default 0, when updated set to 1 and on the trigger only update rows with bit = 0. But you should do that calculation on the insert i guess

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a where to indicate which row to update. For example look at this query:

```
declare @var table (id int)
update Cities
set fullname = 'Melbourne'
output inserted.id into @var 
where name = 'MEL'

select * from @var
```

if you inital update command uses the output command you then use @var.id in your trigger to limit the rows.

```
where t1.id = @var.id
```

depending on the rest of your system you might need to work on this a bit more to pass the id to the trigger.

better would be to write a stored procedure to update the table and have the logic there, save some cpu cycles and IO.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a flag column in the table which indicates the whether rebate is applied or not..(this is not the exact sql query to do the update u need add inserted table to get the data)

```
UPDATE t1
SET     price=  CASE  WHEN column1='Rebate'   THEN price*0.5
ELSE price
END,flag = 'Rebate applied'
where flag != 'Rebate applied' -- change flag to bit
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you triggers updates **ALL ROWS** in your table every time you insert anything.

What you need to do is to include the values from the `Inserted` pseudo table - that table lists all the rows that were **actually inserted** - so you could update **just those** (and leave anything else untouched).

So try to change your trigger to something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri ON dbo.t1
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE t1
    SET price = CASE 
                   WHEN column1 = 'Rebate' THEN price * 0.5
                                           ELSE price 
                END
    FROM Inserted i          -- This is the pseudo table with all inserted rows
    WHERE i.ID = t1.ID       -- make a WHERE condition to match rows up, based on some "ID" column
```